# Custom UITabBar with vertically aligned images

Tags: ios, swift, uitabbar, uitabbaritem

Is there a way to make a the UITabBar show just images that fill the entire TabBarItem? 
I tried simply placing an image and deleting the text in the item's title but the image always appears off-center (the area where the title text was remains and I can't align the image to be over it)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Change image inset of UITabBarItem in UITabBar. You could adjust the image inset to make image bigger, smaller, shift to right etc.

Comment: Tried that, the vertical inset does not work past the area where the title text was. I can use it to move the image further up but that is not what I want.

Comment: I tried it using the controls in the storyboard as well as programically

Comment: It is difficult to say without looking at code or Storyboard. I tried in a test project in Storyboard and it seems to be working fine for me.

Comment: correction, the inset works but it causes a wired visual bug. When I run the app on my phone and tap the TabBarItem, if I hold my finger down on the tabbarimage and move it around it causes the image to grow bigger... So strange.

Comment: The trick is to set BOTH top and bottom insets, making one the negative value of the other (eg. UITabBarItem.imageInsets.top = 5 AND UITabBarItem.imageInsets.bottom = -5). ALSO, remember to do this BEFORE adding the image.